# cheerio simulate $.not()

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

I have an html that looks like :

```
<div class="info">
      <p>132 Purple Grove</p>
      <p>Albany, Texas 76801</p>
      <p class="phone">
          <span>Phone: (111) 111-1111</span>
      </p>
      <p class="fax">Fax: (111) 111-1111</p>
</div>
```

Using cheerio, I want to get an array with all the p elements not having a class of 'phone' or 'fax'. 
Cheerio doesn't have the .not function, so i am trying to replicate it with a filter like so :

```
var addresslines=$(.info).children('p').filter(function(n){ 
  if(!$(n).hasClass('phone') && !$(n).hasClass('fax')){
    return n;
  }
});
```

I get as a result the following array (I've removed line breaks) which filters out the first element and leaves the others untouched. I can't seem to understand why...

Result :

```
0 Albany, Texas 76801
1 Phone: (111) 111-1111
2 Fax: (111) 111-1111
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2cPLK/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when filter takes a function as a parameter, it fills that function with two parameters; first one is index, and second one is the element. So currently what you have in hand with the variable `n` is an integer, not an element.

```
var addresslines=$('.info').children('p').filter(function(n, el){ 
  if(!$(el).hasClass('phone') && !$(el).hasClass('fax')){
    return el;
  }
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bmVX/1/)

Comment: Another serious case of RTFM... Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

First argument of the `filter` is the index not the element, So you should change your code to this:

```
var addresslines=$(.info).children('p').filter(function(n){ 
    if(!$(this).hasClass('phone') && !$(this).hasClass('fax')){
        return true;
    }
});
```

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2cPLK/1/

Comment: In that case, n is unnecessary too. slightly simpler, but a couple more chars than the accepted answer ;)